# jquery tipsy plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

[Tipsy jquery plugin](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) is installed in my app

This is in my load function

```
 $(function() {
    tipsy();
 });
```

Below code is in a js file

```
var htm = '<div id="new_div" onmouseover="tipsy(this);">' ;

function tipsy(tip)
{
    if ( '' != sumtitle )
    {
        tip.title =  tip.innerHTML;
    }
    else if(tip)
    {
        tip.title =  tip.innerHTML;
    }
    $(tip).tipsy({gravity: 'w'});
}
```

How is that the normal title shows up first and then the jquery tip later.

Comment: I've seen some of your recent questions, and it seems you are struggling a lot with the basics of jQuery. I suggest you take a closer look at jQuery (there are lots of tutorials and books out there). This will help you understand how jQuery can be used, and you'll be able to take full advantage of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tipsy plugin seems to remove the `title` attribute and assign its value to a custom attribute called `original-title` to avoid the default browser tooltip from showing. Maybe in your case, this happens too late: The mouse hovers over the element, this initiates the native browser tooltip. Then, `tipsy()` is executed on the element and switches the attribute name, but that is too late because the timeout for the native tooltip has already started.

You should probably prevent the default action of the event, for example:

```
$('#new_div').bind('mousover', function (e) {
    tipsy(this);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

EDIT: As this does not seem to have the desired effect, please call `tipsy($('#new_div'))` right after the div is created and remove the `mouseover` handler. What you have been doing might be a bit problematic anyway: The tipsy plugin probably uses the `mouseover` event, and you call `.tipsy( { gravity: 'w' } )` in an `onmouseover` event handler. Repeatedly, if you mouseout and then mousover again. That's a lot of unnecessary event assignments.

Comment: If you return false from the function, jQuery will take care of preventing the default and stopping the propagation, etc.

Comment: Well, in this case, you don't necessarily want to stop the propagation, if I understand correctly. Preventing the default action (i.e., the tooltip), is enough.

Comment: Tom i am facing the same problem that u have described and even bind is not working in this case also in jquery-tipsy.js i get an error in tip.remove();

Comment: Thanks Tom i figured out the same..............Thanks for helping me understand this................

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug and will be fixed in the next version. For now please use the "Download Source" link on this commit:

http://github.com/jaz303/tipsy/commit/88923af6ee0e18ac252dfc3034661674b7670a97

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong.
Try this:

```
$('#new_div').tipsy();
```

jQuery is designed for using the selectors in JS code. No onsomething events in HTML, please.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is, instead of using the 'title' attribute, use 'original-title' attribute.